# python/elementtree xml parsing into an array

Tags: python, arrays, xml, elementtree

Starting here:

```
<Program>

    <ManyTag>
        <InstSpecific Inst="FAMU" PgmHrs="120" LimitedAccess="N"/>
        <InstSpecific Inst="FAU" PgmHrs="120" LimitedAccess="N"/>
        <InstSpecific Inst="FIU" PgmHrs="120" LimitedAccess="N"/>
        <InstSpecific Inst="UCF" PgmHrs="120" LimitedAccess="N"/>
        <InstSpecific Inst="UF" PgmHrs="120" LimitedAccess="N"/>
        <InstSpecific Inst="UNF" PgmHrs="120" LimitedAccess="N"/>
        <InstSpecific Inst="USF" PgmHrs="120" LimitedAccess="N"/>
        <InstSpecific Inst="UWF" PgmHrs="120" LimitedAccess="N"/>
        <OtherTags>stuff</OtherTags>
    <ManyTag>

<Program>
```

From above I have a nested grouping of tags that are unique in attrib but not in tag name.  I need to keep this grouping but I cannot figure out how to append the 'Inst' attrib together in an array, document or magical container. Before someone starts hollerin' about code:

```
tree = etree.parse('some.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

inst = []


for element in root.iter():

    if element.tag == 'InstSpecific':
        inst.append(element.get('Inst')
```

This is a short, truncated version but I have tried many things and am nearly blind with rage. I am so frustrated I would do it by hand, but that's over 20,000 entries for the 'InstSpecific' alone. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.findall()` to fin all `InstSpecific` tags and get the `Inst` attributes from the `.attrib`:

```
inst = [element.attrib['Inst'] for element in root.findall('InstSpecific')]
```

If you need to group the list of `Inst` attribute values for every `ManyTag` tag:

```
[element.attrib['Inst']
 for many_tag in tree.findall('ManyTag')
 for element in many_tag.findall('InstSpecific')]
```

Comment: yes, that does work in getting all of the 'Inst'. What I use above also works.  don't think I'm doing a good job explaining. Here is what I am looking for in an array

Comment: yes, that does work in getting all of the 'Inst'. What I use above also works.  don't think I'm doing a good job explaining. Here is what I am looking for in an array, generically speaking:   array = [[Breed][Names]].  This would look like  array = [[Poodle][Fluffy, LadyBug, Snickers]]   The tag would like<Dog Breed="Poodle' Names="Fluffy">  There would be several nested instances of <Dog> and I cannot figure out how to put them in the array so they are associted with a nested cluster of <Dog>.

Comment: @TypeSlow okay, thanks, but what would the desired output be for the xml sample provided in the question?

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Here's what I want.: array = [['FAMU', 'FAU', 'FIU', 'UCF', 'UNF', 'USF', 'UWF']]   Each subsequent row of the array would hold all of the unique 'inst' for that particular nesting of <'IntSpecific>. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @TypeSlow hope I've got what you meant, please see the update.

Comment: alecxe, thank you but I couldn't get the solution to work. This seems to be a rare issue. How does one usually go about collecting all of the same tags with different attrib within a nested structure to then place in an array as one list or write to a csv?